# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE not uploading all the record. it limits to 104445. and no error

Tags: php, mysqli

here is my code.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

include_once('connection.php');

$target ="csv/file_05252017.csv";


$truncateTempTable = mysqli_query($mysqli,"TRUNCATE TABLE temp_location");
if (!$truncateTempTable) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

$loadDataToTempTableSql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$target."' INTO TABLE temp_location FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' IGNORE 1 LINES";

$loadDataToTempTableRes = mysqli_query($mysqli,$loadDataToTempTableSql);

if (!$loadDataToTempTableRes) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

its not giving any error but just uploding to 104445. it suppose to insert all the records which are 600301.

FYI: when i open that csv file i can still see all the records.

Comment: I suspect there's a problem with the record after 104445, maybe it isn't quoted properly.

Comment: What happens if you move that line earlier in the file?

Comment: how i can reach to that record?

Comment: Open it in a text editor and go to that line. Then cut it and paste it near the beginning of the file.